# Yii2 - Unable to parse result of hasMany()

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I got stuck on kinda very basic thing and can not move on. I have tables `interpret` and `interpret_member` like this (just important data here):

```
$this->createTable('interpret', [
    'name'      => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
    'PRIMARY KEY (name)'
]);

$this->createTable('interpret_member', [
    'name'      => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
    'interpret' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
    'PRIMARY KEY (name, interpret)'
]);

$this->createIndex(
    'idx-interpret_member',
    'interpret_member',
    'interpret'
);

$this->addForeignKey('fk-interpret_member', 'interpret_member', 'interpret', 'interpret', 'name', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
```

Then I have models for both tables generated by gii, so I also have method `getInterpretMembers` in `Interpret model`. First I tried to parse its output according to [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record) manual, which gives me an error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`. So I searched here and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367392/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-yii2) thread. Following that I changed my `foreach ($members as $member)` to `foreach ($members->InterpretMember as $member)`. That gave me error `Getting unknown property: yii\db\ActiveQuery::InterpretMember`. The last hope was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125334/yii2-activerecord-to-array) thread, but that ended on error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`. The code of last try was:

```
public function getInterpretMembers()
{
    $members = $this->hasMany(InterpretMember::className(), ['interpret' => 'name']);
    foreach ($members as $member) {
        $member = ArrayHelper::toArray($member, [
            'app\models\user\InterpretMember' => [
                'name',
                'interpret',
                'position'
            ]
        ]);
        echo "Member = {$member->name}<br/>";
    }
    die();
}
```

I used this code for all attempts, it was just modified according to the mentioned threads and manual.

Comment: $members = $this->hasMany(InterpretMember::className(), ['interpret' => 'name']); This return an activeQuery and not actualy the data
Try $members = $this->hasMany(InterpretMember::className(), ['interpret' => 'name'])->all();

Comment: Omg thank you so much! I don't get why it isn't written like this in manual... Can you write it into the Answer section so I can mark you that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite simple

```
$members = $this->hasMany(InterpretMember::className(), ['interpret' => 'name']);
```

The **hasMany** function returns an **ActiveQuery** instance 
and not actually the data from DB,
so in order to get data you need 
to call **one()** or **all()** function from **ActiveQuery** instance

```
$members = $this->hasMany(InterpretMember::className(), ['interpret' => 'name'])->all();
```

Congratulations, now you will have the data

Comment: This solution will break the relation definition so you won't be able to use it where you  need to work with relations. For example you won't be able to use eager loading with `ActiveQuery::with()` method or use relation to create join with `ActiveQuery::joinWith()`.

Comment: @MichalHynčica You are right. I just explained the problems with getting data.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how relations and `ActiveRecord` works in Yii2.

What your models should look like.

Interpret model

```php
class Interpret extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
    * Method that defines the relation. It should
    * return instance of \yii\db\ActiveQuery
    */
    public function getInterpretMembers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InterpretMember::class, ['interpret' => 'name']);
    }

    //... other methods
}
```

InterpretMember model

```php
class InterpretMember extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getInterpret()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Interpret::class, ['name' => 'interpret'])
    }
}
```

This will create property `interpretMembers` in your `Interpret` class and property `interpret` in your `InterpretMember` class.

To work with it in your controller you can do for example following:

```php
class InterpretController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionView()
    {
        //find interpret with name InterpretName
        $interpret = Interpret::findOne('InterpretName');
        //output all members
        foreach ($interpret->interpretMembers as $member) {
            echo "Member = {$member->name}<br/>";
        }
        die();
    }
}
```

Or if you want to work with members inside of Interpret class:

```php
class Interpret extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
    * Method that defines the relation. It should
    * return instance of \yii\db\ActiveQuery
    */
    public function getInterpretMembers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InterpretMember::class, ['interpret' => 'name']);
    }

    //... other methods

    public function doSomethingWithMembers()
    {
        foreach ($this->interpretMembers as $member) {
            echo "Member = {$member->name}<br/>";
        }
        die();
    }
}
```